# Spring boot thymeleaf cannot access attributes

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I followed the spring boot thymeleaf tutorial [here](https://hellokoding.com/spring-boot-hello-world-example-with-thymeleaf/).

**HelloController.java**

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping({"/", "/hello"})
    public String hello(Model model, @RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**hello.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'"></title>
    <link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h2 class="hello-title" th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'"></h2>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

The css and js files are identical as on the link above.

However when I go to the *localhost:8080/hello?name=test*, I only see the "hello" returned. Also, when in the *hello.html*, Intellij highlights `${name}` and says *cannot resolve name*; though scouring the internet leads me to believe that this is an IntelliJ issue.

Note, when I debug, the *name* actually does get set in the `Controller`.

Am I missing something to tie in the model attribute and thymeleaf name?

Thanks

Comment: You're using `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`.  If you use `@RestController`, it assumes you are returning a string to be consumed by ajax/webservices instead of returning a Thymeleaf template.

Comment: @Metroids wow. Thanks. Answer it and I'll accept